# php exec() not showing expected output

Tags: php, c++, exec

I am trying to run cpp executable on php, but its not working. Please help.

```
 var_dump(shell_exec("D:\\c_cpp_programs\\string.exe"));
 $output = system('D:\\c_cpp_programs\\string.exe', $retval);
 var_dump($output);
 passthru ('D:\\c_cpp_programs\\string.exe');
 if(file_exists('D:/c_cpp_programs/string.exe'))
    echo "File exist";
 exec('D:/c_cpp_programs/string.exe',$array,$error);
 var_dump($array);
 var_dump($error);
```

below is the output I get,

```
C:\wamp64\www\chatclub\application\views\test.php:2:null
C:\wamp64\www\chatclub\application\views\test.php:4:string '' (length=0)
File exist
C:\wamp64\www\chatclub\application\views\test.php:9:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\chatclub\application\views\test.php:10:int -1073741515
```

cpp program is,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){   
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives me the output on PHP Interactive shell though,

```
C:\Users\Shoyeb>php -a
Interactive shell

php > var_dump(shell_exec("D:\\c_cpp_programs\\string.exe"));
string(5) "Hello"
php > var_dump(shell_exec("D:\\c_cpp_programs\\string.exe"));
string(6) "Hello
" <----- this output is with <<endl
php > var_dump(shell_exec("D:\\c_cpp_programs\\string.exe"));
string(5) "Hello"
php >
```

Comment: Just consult the manual, which is full of examples per function. That would have also led you into trying [`proc_open()`](https://www.php.net/proc_open). As for [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) the manual clearly says trailing whitespaces per line aren't captured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the output when I started wamp with admin privileges,

```
C:\wamp64\www\chatclub\application\views\test.php:2:string 'Hello
' (length=6)
Hello
C:\wamp64\www\chatclub\application\views\test.php:4:string 'Hello' (length=5)
Hello File exist
C:\wamp64\www\chatclub\application\views\test.php:9:
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Hello' (length=5)
C:\wamp64\www\chatclub\application\views\test.php:10:int 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
exec("D:/c_cpp_programs/string.exe", $out);
```

Note that `$out` will hold the output.
Remember that`shell_exec` returns all of the output stream as a string, but `exec` returns the last line of the output.

I'm not cpp expert but `<<endl` may output a empty string. I'm not sure.

Comment: I removed <<endl from cpp program, still it wont show Hello on php.